# Monitoring: Quota exceeded: Your table exceeded quota for imports or query appends per table

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, bigdata

We're getting this error periodically despite what I believe to be usage well under the 1000 batch daily updates per table.

My problem is that there's no way to inspect what Google believes the current usage is for a particular table. This makes it impossible to isolate the underlying process that is responsible for the majority of the quota usage.

How can we view/inspect the current usage levels for this quota?

Answer (score 2):

I would start by enabling audit logs and inspecting the logs.

Audit logs are available via Google Cloud Logging, where they can be immediately filtered to provide insights on specific jobs or queries, or exported to Google Cloud Pub/Sub, Google Cloud Storage, or BigQuery.

To analyze your aggregated BigQuery usage using SQL, set up export of audit logs back to BigQuery. For more information about setting up exports from Cloud Logging, see Overview of Logs Export in the [Cloud Logging documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2).

Analyzing Audit Logs Using BigQuery: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers. If they questions are duplicate **vote** to close one as the duplicate of the other. If they're not duplicates then *tailor your answer to the specifics of each question*.

Comment: I'm not sure which logs are the Audit logs. I already have Stackdriver logging enabled and that is where I was able to examine the Quota Exceeded error. My issue isn't finding when the issue occurs. My problem is I have no way of knowing the current state of the system. For instance I want to know that at this exact moment I have 462 out of 1000 daily batch updates for table X.